# Problems redirecting a URL within a URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This might look like a strange issue, but due to a href mistake on one of my pages (which is now fixed) Google Webmaster Tools is telling me I have thousands of broken URLs looking like this:

> http://www.website.com/folder/**http://www.website.com/folder**/article/subject/content.php?id=12345

It should look like this:

> http://www.website.com/folder/article/subject/content.php?id=12345

I want to redirect them to the correct location, to satisfy my Webmaster Tools error list. The correct URL is without the **http://www.website.com/folder** within it.

I have tried quite a few combinations of things to redirect this URL without the second **http://www.website.com/folder** but it's either having no effect at all or throwing up an internal server error/503 error

Here's what I have:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/http://www\.website\.com/folder/article/subject/(.*)\.php?id=(.*) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^folder/http://www\.website\.com/folder/article/subject/(.*)\.php?id=(.*)$ /folder/article/subject/$1.php?id=$2 [R=301,L]
```

I have successful redirects running already in my .htaccess file, but this 'URL within URL' is stumping me.

Ideally I'd redirect the exact URL, but even a wildcards in place of the http://www.website.com/ would work. Can anyone see an glaring errors I've made which are stopping it from working?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 variants.

1) You have a rule that rewrites several slashes to 1
Then write

```
RewriteRule ^folder/http:/www\.website\.com/folder/article/subject/(.*)\.php?id=(.*)$ /folder/subject/article/$1.php?id=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Pay attention to `http:/`

2) Try

```
RewriteRule ^folder/http.//www\.website\.com/folder/article/subject/(.*)\.php?id=(.*)$ /folder/subject/article/$1.php?id=$2 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^folder/http../www\.website\.com/folder/article/subject/(.*)\.php?id=(.*)$ /folder/subject/article/$1.php?id=$2 [R=301,L]
```

or similar variations